# Not able to return Tuple in Test C#

Tags: c#, tuples

I need to return a tuple response. Here is my code:

```
        public Task<(List<AzureADUser> users, Dictionary<string, int> nonUserGraphObjects, string nextPageUrl, IGroupTransitiveMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage usersFromGroup)> GetNextUsersPageAsync(string nextPageUrl, IGroupTransitiveMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage usersFromGroup)
        {
            var users = new List<AzureADUser>();
            var nonUserGraphObjects = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            return (users, nonUserGraphObjects, "", null);
        }
```

On testing this, I get an error:

```
Tuple with 4 elements cannot be converted to type 'Task<(List<AzureADUser> users, Dictionary<string, int> nonUserGraphObjects, string nextPageUrl, IGroupTransitiveMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage usersFromGroup)>'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `On testing this` ---  do you mean it is runtime error, not compile error?

Comment: You need to return a Task...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem isn't the tuple - it's the task. Your method declares that it returns a task. You're trying to return the value directly. That would work if your method is async, but it's not.

Perhaps you meant:

```cs
return Task.FromResult((users, nonUserGraphObjects, "", (IGroupTransitiveMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage) null));
```

As an aside, I would strongly consider introducing an abstraction for this return type if you can - when the return type declaration for a method (even without the `Task<>` part) is 159 characters, that's really not great for readability.